# How to display Image on the List and Form Screens in j2me (java)

Tags: java-me, lcdui, midp-2.0

I want to display an Image on LCDUI List Screen Header and form Screen Header(Top)
when we create a List like this
    List list=new List("Title",List.Implicit);
then will see the title on the List Screen Header(on Top),similarly for Form also
But ,My Requirement is to  display an Image Beside "Title" on List Screen Header(on Top) and form Screen Header?How can i display?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

List list = new List("Title", List.IMPLICIT, listText, listImage);